# Error: fix the version conflict (google-services plugin 11.6.0)

Tags: android, gradle

Im trying to use GoogleSignIn for an app but I cant resolve this issue. I read that to use GoogleSignIn class you should use the e 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.6.0' version so I updated my gradle to this:

```
dependencies {
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.6'
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

compile 'com.crystal:crystalrangeseekbar:1.0.0'
compile 'com.mikhaellopez:circularimageview:3.0.2'
compile 'com.estimote:sdk:0.11.0@aar'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.23.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.6.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.6.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.6.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.6.0'
compile 'com.gtomato.android.library:carouselview:2.0.1'
compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.8.1'
compile 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'
compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.0.0-RC1'
implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.0.0-RC1'
}
```

But I have the same mistake over and over again. Any idea about how to solve it? Also I have this btw.

```
buildscript {
ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.51'
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.google.com'
    }
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'

}}
```

The message:

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.

> Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 11.6.0.

Comment: You missed one. `firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.6`, which is a duplicate of another anyway, so you can  delete it

Comment: Also, `compile 'com.google.gms:google-services` shouldn't be there with the other libraries , and you have two dependencies blocks?

Comment: @cricket_007 I updated my question. I dont have two dependecies blocks. The last one is from Module:app.

Comment: Okay, well, did you see my other comment?

Comment: Yep, I didnt see the firebase line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the same version for the google play service libraries and firebase libraries.
Change:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.6'
```

with

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.6.0'
```